# how to read a txt file with spaces and line breaks into it

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have a flatfile **database-001.txt** file in which entries. My txt file looks like this:

```
Bill

message Bill goes here
1571436403

==
John

message John goes here
1571436126

==
Earl

message earl goes here 
1571436051

==
```

For reading the .txt file, i use this code:

```
$flatfile = file_get_contents('database-001.txt');
echo $flatfile;
?>
```

But using it like this, it generates this:

```
Bill message Bill goes here 1571436403==Johnmessage John goes here1571436126==Earlmessage earl goeshere 1571436051==
```

How can i read the content with the line breaks and white lines in it exactly as in the .txt file?

Comment: Are you viewing the results in a browser?

Comment: yes i view the results in a browser

Comment: Than display it in `<pre>` tags.

Comment: @kaczmen. This makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$flatfile = file_get_contents('database-001.txt');
echo nl2br($flatfile);
```

What is happening is, the browser doesn't understand `\n`. You should use `<br>` instead. `nl2br` transforms all classic new lines `\n` to `<br>`.

You can easily see this with the following example:

```
$str1 = "regular \n newline";
$str2 = "browser <br> newline";
echo str1;
echo str2;
```